# How to display the content of Spring Webflow's "flowScope" in a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-webflow

I'd like to list out everything that's in the various webflow context scopes (viewScope, flowScope, etc) on my JSP pages for debugging purposes (first webflow app, trying to get it working.)   But I can't seem to get the syntax right.     Can anyone tell me how to do this?  I have this in my flow.xml:

```
<view-state id="createAccount" model="account">
    <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="flowService.createAccount()" result="flowScope.account" />
    </on-render>
    <transition on="next" to="applicationInfo" />
</view-state>
```

and I have this in my JSP page:

```
<c:forEach items="${flowScope}" var="thisFlowScope" varStatus="thisFlowScopeStatus">
    <label>${thisFlowScope.key}</label>
    <span>${thisFlowScope.value}</span>
</c:forEach>
```

What I was hoping to see was the "account" attribute/variable printed out along with everything else in the flowScope.   Instead I get nothing.   I have tried various permutations such as "flowRequestContext" instead of "flowScope".    With "flowRequestContext" I get:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:255)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:219)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:137)
    javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:227)
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: For those that might need the exact syntax, add this "evaluate" expression to your view-state tag:             
            <evaluate expression="flowRequestContext.flowScope.asMap()" result="requestScope.flowAsMap" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flowScope is a [MutableAttributeMap](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/webflow/core/collection/MutableAttributeMap.html).

You can not itarate over it. That's why working with `c:forEach` will not work.

However:
You can print the whole map with `${flowRequestContext.flowScope}` but this looks not pretty.

There is a function called `asMap` inherited from `org.springframework.binding.collection.MapAdaptable` which converts it to a java.util.Map (which is of course iterable)

Comment: Thanks!   This appears to be the answer to the problem, but I can't figure out the syntax to call asMap() from an EL expression.   I get this error:    "The function asMap must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified."   I hate to be greedy, but do you know how to do this?

Comment: yes. i was confused when i tried it. but you can store the output of `asMap` in the flow scope and then iterate over it using `c:forEach`

Comment: Yes, this worked!   I had to store it in a separate variable in the flow definition (in "flow.xml") but it did in fact work.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I add my examples based on responses Philipp Sander and "user1071914":

flow.xml:

```
<view-state id="display" view="/WEB-INF/jsp/infoUser.jsp" model="dtoUser">
   <on-entry>
      <evaluate expression="flowRequestContext.flowScope.asMap()" result="requestScope.flowAsMap" />
   <on-entry>
   <transition on="next" to="checkUserAction" />
</view-state>

<action-state id="checkUserAction">
  ...
</action-state>
```

View JSP:

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.flowAsMap['myvarflowScope']}" />
```